# Merge two datatables in powershell

Tags: powershell, datatable

I've got two datatables of information. The first is a simple one.

```
Name, Location
VM1, C:\VM1\VM1.VHD
VM2, C:\VM2\VM2.VHD
VM2, C:\VM2\VM2_1.VHD
```

I iterate through the top table using foreach and get more information about each Location and end up with a second object that holds the information about the Location in question.

So for each object, I get Size,Type,Filesize,MinimumSize values.

What I'd like to do is create a new datatable that has

```
Name, Location, Size, Type, Filesize, MinimumSize
VM1, C:\VM1\VM1.VHD, ######, IDE, #####, ###
```

How do I go about concatenating my new Values to the existing table above or create a new table containing all the information?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want Add-Member. It can be used as such:

```
$Table1 | ForEach{ <Do stuff to get $properties>
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Size' -Value $Properties.size
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Type -Value $Properties.Type
    ...add more members...
    }
```

If you have a newer version (3 or higher) of PowerShell you can simplify that Add-Member to:

```
$_ | Add-Member 'Size' $Properties.size
```

It will assume (if an object is piped into it and there are only 2 arguments) that the first argument is the name, and the second is the value of a NoteProperty.